# php check if domain equals value, then perform action

Tags: php

I need to take a variable that contains a URL, and check to see if the domain equals a certain domain, if it does, echo one variable, if not, echo another.

```
$domain = "http://www.google.com/docs";
if ($domain == google.com)
{ echo "yes"; }
else
{ echo "no"; }
```

Im not sure how to write the second line where it checks the domain to see if $domain contains the url in the if statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is done by using [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url):

```
$host = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
if($host == 'www.google.com') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You probably want more robust domain checking, as noted in Jonathan Sampson's answer.

Comment: How is a homemade regex more robust than a PHP built in?

Answer (score 7):

Slightly more advanced domain-finding function.

```
$address = "http://www.google.com/apis/jquery";

if (get_domain($address) == "google.com") {
  print "Yes.";
}

function get_domain($url)
{
    $pieces = parse_url($url);
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
    if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
        return $regs['domain'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers you could use a regex, like this one which looks for google.com in the domain name

```
$domain = "http://www.google.com/docs";
if (preg_match('{^http://[\w\.]*google.com/}i', $domain))
{

}
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't see what you were trying there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `parse_url()`?

Note that you might also want to `explode()` the resulting domain on `'.'`, depending on exactly what you mean by 'domain'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [parse_url function](http://no.php.net/parse_url) to divide the URL into the separate parts (protocol/host/path/query string/etc). If you also want to allow www.google.com to be a synonym for google.com, you'll need to add an extra substring check (with substr) that makes sure that the latter part of the host matches the domain you're looking for.