# Simple regex for domain names

Tags: php, regex, dns

How to make sure that the domain name match those 3 simple criterias :

- Ends with .com / .net

**Must not start with**

- http:// or https://
- http://www. or https://www.

I've managed to understand this part of the regex which correspond with the first criteria :

```
/.*(\.com|\.net)$/
```

But i have no idea how to achieve the 2 others conditions to make an unique regex.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you need to be sure that a string will not contain the first two points, why don't you simply use str_replace and then test for the first criteria? I think it will be more easy and surely more efficient.

Comment: make the regex match the http:// etc. and then get the ! of the bool returned

Comment: Well, yeah, you're right, it'll be much easy. i could work with that. :-)

Comment: Your formulation of the problem is much too simplistic.  This cannot be solved by regex in the general case.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain/1201210#comment26755649_1201210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex solution is easy. Simply assert a negative lookahead at the start of the string like so: (With comments...)

```php
if (preg_match('%
    # Match non-http ,com or .net domain.
    ^             # Anchor to start of string.
    (?!           # Assert that this URL is NOT...
      https?://   # HTTP or HTTPS scheme with
      (?:www\.)?  # optional www. subdomain.
    )             # End negative lookahead.
    .*            # Match up to TLD.
    \.            # Last literal dot before TLD.
    (?:           # Group for TLD alternatives.
      net         # Either .net
    | com         # or .com.
    )             # End group of TLD alts.
    $             # Anchor to end of string.
    %xi', $text)) {
    // It matches.
} else {
    // It doesn't match.
}
```

Note that since: `http://www.` is a subset of: `http://`, the expression for the optional `www.` is not necessary. Here is a shorter version:

```php
if (preg_match('%^(?!https?://).*\.(?:net|com)$%i', $text)) {
    // It matches.
} else {
    // It doesn't match.
}
```

Simple regex to the rescue!

Answer (score 5):

"Not starting" with a pattern is a bit tricky.

The clearest way of doing it is two separate regexes, one to match what you want and one not matching what you don't want.

But you *can* do this in one with a negative look-ahead:

```
/^(?!https?:\/\/(www\.)?).*(\.com|\.net)$/
```

**Edit**: correct the assertion as pointed out by ridgerunner

Comment: Won't work. From the beginning of the string, `^` you want to use negative _lookahead_ NOT negative lookbehind. The expression needed here is: `/^(?!https?:\/\/(www\.)?).*(\.com|\.net)$/`

Comment: @Ridgerunner: You're right. I've corrected it. Tricky things, these lookarounds.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be sure that a string will not contain the first two points, why don't you simply use str_replace and then test for the first criteria? I think it will be more easy and surely more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z\.]+\.(com|net)$
```

does this work?

well if I understood you right, you want to check a list of String, and find out which are domain names.  e.g.

```
http://www.a.b (F)
a.com (T)
b.net  (T)
https://google.com (F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:http://|https://)(?:[w]{3}|)/i', $subject))
{
  echo 'Fail';
}
else
{
  if(preg_match('/(?:.*(\.com|\.net))$/i', $subject))
  {
    echo 'Pass';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Fail';
  }
}
```