# How to extract domain names from text using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, text

How can I extract the domain name from some text using PHP?

For example, my text should be something like following:

```
[amr]http://www.example1.com[amr]4[amr]af[amrlf]7
[amr]http://www.example1.com[amr]2[amr]ad[amrlf]22
[amr]http://www.example1.net[amr]1[amr]ad[amrlf]26
[amr]http://www.example1.info[amr]3[amr]af[amrlf]31
```

Now I just want to get the domain name from this without `http://` or `www`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Your text doesn't make any sense. What are "[amr]" and "[amrlf]" supposed to represent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple regex for domain names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742010/simple-regex-for-domain-names)

Comment: This just a small portion of a text from a file and it can be anything like [amr], 2[amr],ad[amrlf],22[amr] and my requirement is to get the domain name from that text.

Comment: @ Colin Fine That can be anything(special characters, numeric or alphabets) after the valid domain and I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @ mario The link you mentioned here is not the duplicate of my question. Please do check the question before making comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$str = '[amr]http://www.example1.com[amr]4[amr]af[amrlf]7[amr]http://www.example1.com[amr]2[amr]ad[amrlf]22[amr]http://www.example1.net[amr]1[amr]ad[amrlf]26[amr]http://www.example1.info[amr]3[amr]af[amrlf]31';
preg_match_all('#http://(?:www\.)?(.*?)\[amr#', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => example1.com
    [1] => example1.com
    [2] => example1.net
    [3] => example1.info
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much M42.This regular expression is working fine with the above string, but not with my file of text(This text is from a file and Iam reading the file contents to a variable). I just copied the portion of the string in my question. Do I need to upload the file ?

Comment: If the file is not too big, you can read it in a string and then apply the `preg_match_all` command on this string. If it's too big, process line by line.

Comment: File is not so big, just 2 MB of size. Yes I did exactly what you said in your comment, I took the file contents as a string(using file_get_contents()) and applied the regular expression provided by you. But no luck.  Once again thanks for giving reply.              About file upload in the first comment : I asked whether stackoverflow has any option to upload the file with the question, so that I can upload that file to give more clarification.

Comment: What is not working? What did you get? Edit your question and say what you obtain.

Comment: It is working fine now.  Earlier the code was like this $file           = file_get_contents('file2.txt'); 
     preg_match_all('#http://(?:www\.)?(.*?)\[amr#', $file, $matches);
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($matches[1]); and this was not working for me.
         
     Then I modified the code by giving whole string to $file in code itself and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution :)

```
$url  = 'http://google.com?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
```