# Select domain name from text, display message

Tags: dns

This is kind of complicated, two questions in one - 1) how to select a domain name from text stored in a database table and 2) how to display a message related to that domain name. I thought if I explained the whole project first I might at least get some tips that steer me in the right direction.

OK, imagine an article stored in a database table. The article includes a few links, like these:

```
http://www[.]mysite[.]com/Life
http://www[.]mysite2[.]com/World/Africa
http://www[.]google[.]com/help
http://en[.]wikipedia[.]com
```

(Note: I inserted brackets because the forumbot apparently thinks I'm posting links to other websites, rather than examples.)

If I'm surfing mysite.com, I'd like to distinguish between...

1) links to other pages on that site (no message required)
2) links to allied websites (e.g. mysite2.com)
3) links to "foreign" websites (e.g. Google)
4) possibly links to particular websites, like Wikipedia

I'd then like to display some sort of message or warning, as follows:

1) (no message required)
2) "Note: You are leaving mysite.com for an allied website)"
3) "Note: You are leaving the MySite family of websites. Please visit again!"
4) "Warning: You are following a link to Wikipedia. Be warned that its articles may not be accurate."

So, let's say I query my database table and display an article like this...

echo $Text;

What's a good way to search that text for links and select any domain names? Then how would I match that domain name to a list of names in a switch, like the one below?

```
switch($Domain)
{
 case 'mysite[.]com':
 // (Do nothing)
 break;
 case 'google[.]com':
 // Display message
 break;
 case 'en.wikipedia[.]org':
 // Display warning
 break;
 default:
 break;
}
```

Next, I have to figure out how to display a message or popup. On second thought, I should probably make that a separate question (if necessary). This has turned into a long question(s) to begin with.

P.S. I have found several posts that explain how to use regex to obtain domain names, like this one:
[Simple regex for domain names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742010/simple-regex-for-domain-names?lq=1)

The answers may be there, but I haven't quite figured out how to put it all together. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. But I hope you decide not to do this because, in my opinion, it's pretty obnoxious. Links are links. If people want to follow them, they don't care that they're "leaving the MySite family of websites". The most you should probably do is postfix these "external" links with a little "external" icon.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty good tip. I don't know if it's too late to rephrase my question or if I need to start a new discussion, but I'll try it first:

How can I write a script that would pick out URLs (anything following "http://" or "https://" then pick out the domain name so I could insert a tiny icon with a str_replace, something like this?:

$Text = str_replace('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.com<image>', $Text);