# Programmatically get domain for cookie

Tags: php, regex, cookies

I want to set the domain for a cookie and the session cookie so it applies to all sub-domains. I know I can do this using the following:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
set_cookie('name', value, expires, '/', '.example.com');
```

How do I get `.example.com` from the server variables in PHP? The problem is, I need to get it to work for all types of domain patterns, e.g.

- www.example.com
- example.com
- example.co.uk
- subdomain.example.co.uk
- sub1.sub2.example.co.uk
- etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1201210/562697) and came up with the following solution that works most of the time, with the exception of 3 or less characters in domain name with a 2 character TLD (like www.ex.co):

```
$domain = false;
$host = parse_url('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], PHP_URL_HOST);
if(preg_match('/([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $host, $m)) {
    $domain = $m[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable. It will return the host in which the script is being executed.

If you want a specific part you can use explode.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$host = implode(".", ($temp[count($temp) - 1], $temp[count($temp) - 2]));
```

I do not recommend it, for instance a .co.uk domain would be caught incorrectly. You got the idea.

Comment: It also returns the subdomain the script is executed in, and I don't want that piece.

Comment: Ok that should do it, I think it is a bad idea though.

Comment: I am not 100% what you are trying to do there and it generates an error of `unexpected ,` on the second line. Also, I am only using this as the default value in a setup script, so the user has the option to change to specify the domains they really want to use, if not all.

Comment: Explode splits a string into parts based on a delimiter, dot. Then you stick the last 2 pieces together.

Comment: That's what I thought. You are missing `array` before the parenthesis, and that doesn't work for TLDs like `.co.uk`

Comment: :/ What did you thought I implied with:  for instance a .co.uk domain would be caught incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be impossible, without an array containing values.
Possible to avoid the iteration into array to check for +- all domains, but not for all. With something like this (that maybe can be improved) you'll get ever the correct cookie domain name. It iterate only one time the array, and checking for one value:
https://www.axew3.com/w3/2017/05/extract-domain-name-for-cookie-php-function/

EDITED: the code has been improved.

**IMPROVED VERSION:**

```
$w3domains = array(".aero",".biz",".cat",".com",".coop",".edu",".gov",".info",".int",".jobs",".mil",".mobi",".museum",
    ".name",".net",".org",".travel",".ac",".ad",".ae",".af",".ag",".ai",".al",".am",".an",".ao",".aq",".ar",".as",".at",".au",".aw",
    ".az",".ba",".bb",".bd",".be",".bf",".bg",".bh",".bi",".bj",".bm",".bn",".bo",".br",".bs",".bt",".bv",".bw",".by",".bz",".ca",
    ".cc",".cd",".cf",".cg",".ch",".ci",".ck",".cl",".cm",".cn",".co",".cr",".cs",".cu",".cv",".cx",".cy",".cz",".de",".dj",".dk",".dm",
    ".do",".dz",".ec",".ee",".eg",".eh",".er",".es",".et",".eu",".fi",".fj",".fk",".fm",".fo",".fr",".ga",".gb",".gd",".ge",".gf",".gg",".gh",
    ".gi",".gl",".gm",".gn",".gp",".gq",".gr",".gs",".gt",".gu",".gw",".gy",".hk",".hm",".hn",".hr",".ht",".hu",".id",".ie",".il",".im",
    ".in",".io",".iq",".ir",".is",".it",".je",".jm",".jo",".jp",".ke",".kg",".kh",".ki",".km",".kn",".kp",".kr",".kw",".ky",".kz",".la",".lb",
    ".lc",".li",".lk",".lr",".ls",".lt",".lu",".lv",".ly",".ma",".mc",".md",".mg",".mh",".mk",".ml",".mm",".mn",".mo",".mp",".mq",
    ".mr",".ms",".mt",".mu",".mv",".mw",".mx",".my",".mz",".na",".nc",".ne",".nf",".ng",".ni",".nl",".no",".np",".nr",".nu",
    ".nz",".om",".pa",".pe",".pf",".pg",".ph",".pk",".pl",".pm",".pn",".pr",".ps",".pt",".pw",".py",".qa",".re",".ro",".ru",".rw",
    ".sa",".sb",".sc",".sd",".se",".sg",".sh",".si",".sj",".sk",".sl",".sm",".sn",".so",".sr",".st",".su",".sv",".sy",".sz",".tc",".td",".tf",
    ".tg",".th",".tj",".tk",".tm",".tn",".to",".tp",".tr",".tt",".tv",".tw",".tz",".ua",".ug",".uk",".um",".us",".uy",".uz", ".va",".vc",
    ".ve",".vg",".vi",".vn",".vu",".wf",".ws",".ye",".yt",".yu",".za",".zm",".zr",".zw");

$w3cookie_domain = 'axew3.com';
//$w3cookie_domain = 'sub.mydomain.eu';
//$w3cookie_domain = 'tes.originalgangster.co.uk';
//$w3cookie_domain = 'sub3.sub2.sub1.example.co.uk';
//$w3cookie_domain = 'subdomain.example.co.uk';
//$w3cookie_domain = 'sub1.sub2.example.it';
//$w3cookie_domain = 'example.co.uk';

$count_dot = substr_count($w3cookie_domain, ".");

     if($count_dot >= 3){
      preg_match('/.*(\.)([-a-z0-9]+)(\.[-a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z]+)/', $w3cookie_domain, $w3m0, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
      $w3cookie_domain = $w3m0[2][0].$w3m0[3][0].$w3m0[4][0];
   }

   $ckcd = explode('.',$w3cookie_domain);

  if(!in_array('.'.$ckcd[1], $w3domains)){
   $w3cookie_domain = preg_replace('/^[^\.]*\.([^\.]*)\.(.*)$/', '\1.\2', $w3cookie_domain);
  }

    $w3cookie_domain = '.' . $w3cookie_domain;

    echo $w3cookie_domain;
```