# How do I split a domain name into sld and tld(extension)?

Tags: php, regex

The domain's need to be returned as the actual domain name, and the extension, separately

```
http://www.something.com
```

should return: `sld = something`, `tld= com`

```
something.co.uk
```

should return: `sld = something`, `tld= co.uk`

I am not much familiar with regular expressions, so I really need some help in handling this.

I suppose I can use `parse_url()`, and check the `host`, but what then?

Comment: In your second example `co` is the SLD and `uk` is the TLD.

Comment: THis may helps you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain

Comment: You need a list of tlds. Without this list, domain names such as www.bbc.co.uk are ambiguous (www, bbc.co, uk or www, bbc, co.uk).

Comment: You can use this API endpoint to get it correct tld and all other details abou the URL: https://www.geekystats.com/api/v1/urlDetails?url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you said, you can use `$urlCompontents=parseUrl($url)` to get the hostname. Then you could use `explode(".",$urlCompontents["host"])` to split the hostname into the different parts, e.G. `array("example","co","uk")`. You'll have to do the rest by comparing the parts against a list, because there is no fixed rule that e.G. "uk" by itself is not considered a TLD but "co.uk" is. But you don't need any regular expressions here.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the [PHP Explode Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a limit of two.

Example 1:

```
var_dump(explode('.','example.com',2));
```

Example 1 Result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "example" [1]=> string(3) "com" }
```

Example 2:

```
var_dump(explode('.','example.uk.com',2));
```

Example 2 Result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "example" [1]=> string(6) "uk.com" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use. Hope it helps.

```
function extractTLD( $domain )
{
    $productTLD = '';
    $tempstr = explode(".", $domain);
    unset($tempstr[0]);
    foreach($tempstr as $value){
        $productTLD = $productTLD.".".$value;
    }    
    return $productTLD;
}
```

Comment: this is badly written, by removing the first part of the domain you are always expecting a www. or other subdomain, this does not cater for domain.com formats

Answer (score 2):

Use `parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST)` to get the host name; then use the function below to split the domain into parts:

```
function split_domain($host,$SLDs='co|com|edu|gov|mil|net|org')
{
    $parts=explode('.',$host);
    $index=count($parts)-1;
    if($index>0 && in_array($parts[$index-1],explode('|',$SLDs))) $index--;
    if($index===0) $index++;
    $subdomain=implode('.',array_slice($parts,0,$index-1));
    $domain=$parts[$index-1];
    $tld=implode('.',array_slice($parts,$index));
    return array($subdomain,$domain,$tld);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on `.` characters (no need to regex), then work through the resulting array from the end.

You'll need to manually keep an index of which SLDs are sold directly to end users as there is no simple pattern that describes them accurately.

Keep in mind that there is likely to be an [influx of new TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Proposed_domains).

Answer (score 0):

Below code will split (explode) the host string on '.' character. A simple exception array of tld's is needed and I put already co.uk in it. And only for these exceptions it will use the last two chunks of the host name.

```
$h='something.co.uk';
$x=array('uk'=>'co'); // exceptions of tld's with 2 parts
$r=explode('.',$h); // split host on dot
$t=array_pop($r); // create tld
if(isset($x[$t]) and end($r)==$x[$t]) $t=array_pop($r).'.'.$t; // add to tld for the exceptions
$d=implode('.',$r); // domain
echo "sld:$d, tld:$t";
```

The result is sld:something, tld:co.uk

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos = strpos('domain.com', '.');
$length= strlen('domain.com');
$domain = substr('domain.com', 0, $pos);
$tld= substr('domain.com', $pos, $length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs to get an updated list of valid TLD's:
http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: It's ridiculous that the IANA allows an arbitrary number of nth-level domains, like example.co.uk, as well as any number of subdomains like a.b.example, because since you can't parse from the left or right, there's no simple, reliable way to ever know the actual "primary" portion of the domain. You could have "amazon.co, amazon.uk, amazon.co.uk, amazon.com.co.uk"... The only way is to have a script that always checks the live list of domains. :-/

Comment: That list is wrong, why not link the officil list from publicsuffix.org? https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat