# Get domain from url (Ideal function)

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url)
>   [PHP Getting Domain Name From Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain)

As i figured out a lot from the examples from the google there are not so universal for getting the domain name from url because of:

1. www
2. subdomains
3. second-level domain (co.uk)

Is there any solution, that can get universally domain.

Comment: Look to the right. See the "Related" section? ----->

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain

Comment: @Paul yes, as see, but as i said before, there is no solution with those 3 things included in one function.

Comment: @Adam there is line: "EDIT: Ignore the .co.uk, presume that all domains going through this function have a 3 letter TLD."

Comment: Why 3 letter TLD? What about country domains (.ca, .cn etc). Do you mean to exclude those?

Comment: this one is not easy (with regular expressions only), because "co" in "co.uk" is (per definition) actually the domain name and everything before ("bbc" in "bbc.co.uk") is already a subdomain. Compare "www.myhost.3.ly" to "www.bbc.co.uk" and you undertand what i mean. [see this post with a few examples on short domains](http://singlefunction.com/the-shortest-url-shorteners/)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following regex in Ruby and it works for me:

```
/(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([-\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/wyR7yvKT6q

But what you mean under **domain**? The above regexp extracts domain correctly

```
http://my.subdomain.ko.uk
to
my.subdomain.ko.uk <-- this is domain
```

Or you can use:

```
.*([^\.]+)(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk|__and so on__)$
/^(?:www\.)?(.*?)\.(?:com|au\.uk|co\.in)$/
```