# PHP if URL equals this then perform action

Tags: php, if-statement

So I have a page title that is part of a Magento template; I'd like it to display 1 of 2 options, depending on what the URL is. If the URL is option 1, display headline 1. If the URL is anything else, display headline 2. This is what I came up with, but it's making my page crash:

```
<div class="page-title">
<h1><?php
$host = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
if($host == 'http://domain.com/customer/account/create/?student=1') {
echo $this->__('Create an account if you are a Post Graduate Endodontic Resident and receive our resident pricing. Please fill in all required fields. Thank you!')
}
else
{
echo $this->__('Create an Account')
}
?></h1>
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: So it should look like this?

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'http://domain.com/customer/account/create/?student=1')
```

Comment: What does "making my page crash" mean? Do you revieve an error message? Further on: Where did you define the variable $domain?

Comment: Everything before this part of the page loads, then it stops. No error message

Comment: I got $domain from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122261/php-check-if-domain-equals-value-then-perform-action

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you looking for the URL that the page is currently on? You are using [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url) the wrong way; that is if you only want to get the host, or domain, i.e. only "dev.obtura.com". It looks like you want more than that. In addition, you are never setting the `$domain` variable, so `parse_url()` doesn't know what to do with it. So as it is now, your `if` statement will always return 'Create an account`.

Instead, set `$host` with [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables:

`$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

You will also need to remove the "http://" from your checking - `$host` will only contain everything after "http://"

As [Aron Cederholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150926/aron-cederholm) suggested, you need to add semicolons (`;`) to the end of your echo statements.

So, your PHP code should look like this:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'domain.com/customer/account/create/?student=1') 
{
    echo $this->__('Create an account if you are a Post Graduate Endodontic Resident and receive our resident pricing. Please fill in all required fields. Thank you!');
}
else
{
    echo $this->__('Create an Account');
}
```

Comment: @miles Edited my answer to contain your observations, for others coming to see the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you're fetching the domain right. I don't really understand parse_url much, and you haven't shown us what `$domain` is defined as.

Normally if I want to get the domain name I would do this: `$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` Then the rest of your code.

That if, else statement seems legit to me, so I would try the above and see how that goes. ;)

Edit: Oops, John beat me to it. :)

Comment: See my edit above. I tried it, but got the same result as before.

Answer (score 5):

You should add semicolons to your statements inside your if-else.

```
if($host == 'http://dev.obtura.com/customer/account/create/?student=1') {
    echo $this->__('Create an account if you are a Post Graduate Endodontic Resident and receive our resident pricing. Please fill in all required fields. Thank you!');
}
else
{
    echo $this->__('Create an Account');
}
```

Comment: The page is no longer crashing, but the statement isn't working. I'm still getting the second 'Create an Account' headline

Comment: Try echoing $host to see for your self why it does not equal to your desired url.

Comment: @miles Did you try setting $host as I suggested?

Comment: Like this: if ($host == '...') { echo 'Success: ', $host, PHP_EOL; echo $this->__('...'); } else { echo 'Fail: ', $host, PHP_EOL; echo $this->__('Create an Account'); }

Comment: Also, try with setting $host in the way @john and Jack BeePee described.