# PHP - different header text on homepage and interior pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to make the pagetitle in the header of the homepage different from that of the interior pages. It seems like a simple php fix but it is over my head. This seemed to be the solution but implementing it gave an error code : [PHP if URL equals this then perform action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523140/php-if-url-equals-this-then-perform-action)

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=GFS+Didot'
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div>
    <header class="pagetitle">
        <h1>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
                <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
            </a>
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Can someone tell me the if/else statement that will give me one  on the homepage and a different on all other pages?

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<title>
    <?php 
        if( is_home() ) {
            echo 'Homepage Title';
        } 
        else {
            echo 'Other Pages Title';
        }
    ?>
</title>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Here's what I use on my own site to display just the site title on the homepage, but the article title on subpages:

```
<title>
    <?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' |'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
</title>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title

Answer (score 1):

```
if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    echo 'HOMEPAGE';
} 
else {
    echo 'INTERIOR PAGES';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most recent edit on [the question you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523140/php-if-url-equals-this-then-perform-action) shows the correct if/else statement:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'your.homepage.com/url/etc') {
  echo "Homepage header text";
}
else {
  echo "Other header text";
}
```

A wordpress-specific solution for checking if the user is on your **home page** is the function `is_home()` which returns a boolean if the main blog page is being displayed. More details about the `is_home()` function found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home). There are also other "conditional tags" in wordpress that come with their own functions. A list of those can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

So for example, you could also rewrite the above PHP code block with the `is_home()` function:

```
if (is_home()) {
  echo "Homepage header text";
}
else {
  echo "Other header text";
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 60 seconds!

Comment: Thanks! So I used the $host version but I'm getting every page to say my else header text. I'm assuming I should be replacing 'SERVER_NAME' with something?'code'  <?php
 $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'homepage.com') {
  echo '<h1>front page text</h1>';
}
else {
  echo '<h1>other text</h1>';
}
?> 'code'