# If [page] within this directory, then.. (IF/THEN as per URL)

Tags: php, if-statement

So I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'domain.com/portfolio/travel/') 
{ ?>
<style>
@import url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/vertical-portfolio.css');
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Based on what I found on [PHP if URL equals this then perform action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523140/php-if-url-equals-this-then-perform-action)

Whilst it works at it's core, it's not /travel itself I want the code imported into, but in actual fact sub's of that (ie travel/bermuda, travel/canada, etc etc)

What variable would I include to go about doing this?

Comment: Your question seems confusing to me.

Comment: Essentially, I want to include a file into a template if that file is WITHIN a certain directory. So domain.com/travel wouldn't call the file, but domain.com/travel/COUNTRY would - where COUNTRY is a variable. TLDR: if file is in folder x, then include.

Comment: may be `strpos` will work in your case like `strpos($host, 'travel')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether the URL begins with that path, use:

```
if (strpos($host, 'domain.com/portfolio/travel/') === 0)
```

Make sure you use the *exact* comparison `===`. If the string isn't found, `strpos()` returns `false`, which will match `0` if you use `==`.

To look only for subdirectories, you can use this:

```
if (preg_match('#^domain.com/portfolio/travel/.*/#', $host))
```

Go to [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) to learn more about regular exressions.

Comment: Will that also apply to portfolio/travel itself? I only want the files WITHIN travel to be affected. I thought there would be a little variable of sorts like if($host == 'domain.com/portfolio/travel/$variable')

Comment: `portfolio/travel` is a directory, not a script.

Comment: I know. I just thought I'd seen a dollar sign + letter to indicate things within a directory once.

Comment: That would be how you _construct_ a pathname that inserts the variable's value into the string. It has nothing to do with pattern matching.

Comment: Ah.

Adjusted code with yours. /travel is affected in addition to the pages therein. Is there any way of excluding the travel tier itself? I suppose (based on how WP constructs things) it'd need only apply to sub-directories rather than pages, assuming /travel calls /travel/indexfileofsomesort.extension

Comment: That's because `/traval` is actually something like `/travel/index.php`, which is in the directory just like all the other scripts there.

Comment: You could use a regular expression.

Comment: Fabulous at CSS. Completely inept at PHP. Laymans would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried using a wildcard (?) -> /travel/* but that doesn't seem to have done anything aside from not work.

Comment: `==` just does simple equality comparison, nothing special related to filenames.

Comment: Does the regular expression solution I added to my answer do what you want?